# Java: Creating a multi threaded reader

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm creating a reader application. The reader identifies based on the parameters which file to read, does some processing and returns the result to the caller.

I am trying to make this multi-threaded, so that multiple requests can be processed. I thought it was simple but later realized it has some complexity. Even though i create threads using executor service, I still need to return the results back to the caller. So this means waiting for the thread to execute.

Only way i can think of is write to some common location or db and let the caller pick the result from there. Is there any approach possible?

Comment: When submitting to an executor service you'll get a future, why don't you wait for its completion?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but it means the process need to wait for the result from the Future.

Comment: So you have to multithread the requests from the processes. From where do you get them? RPC/RMI/Sockets? Would be great if you can show some code ;)

Comment: what is the expected interaction between the "caller" and the worker threads?  you seem to be indicating that the caller is asynchronous, i.e. it submits a request and polls for results later?

Comment: The calls would be across sockets. Haven't written the code yet. Still in the process of designing :)

Comment: Yeah jtahiborn, you are right about interaction. The process will be asynchronous.

Comment: Hey MarianP, are you talking about the question

Answer (score 3):

Maybe an ExecutorCompletionService can help you. The submitted tasks are placed on a queue when completed. You can use the methods take or poll depending on if you want to wait or not for a task to be available on the completion queue.

[ExecutorCompletionService javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ExecutorService` with a thread pool of size > 1, post custom `FutureTask` derivatives which override the `done()` method to signal completion of the task to the UI:

```
public class MyTask extends FutureTask<MyModel> {
  private final MyUI ui;

  public MyTask(MyUI toUpdateWhenDone, Callable<MyModel> taskToRun) {
    super(taskToRun);
    ui=toUpdateWhenDone;
  }
  @Override
  protected void done() {
    try {
      // retrieve computed result
      final MyModel computed=get();
      // trigger an UI update with the new model
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           ui.setModel(computed); // set the new UI model
        }
      });
    }
    catch(InterruptedException canceled) {
       // task was canceled ... handle this case here
    }
    catch(TimeoutException timeout) {
      // task timed out (if there are any such constraints). 
      // will not happen if there are no constraints on when the task must complete
    }
    catch(ExecutionException error) { 
      // handle exceptions thrown during computation of the MyModel object...
      // happens if the callable passed during construction of the task throws an 
      // exception when it's call() method is invoked.
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: For more complex tasks which need to signal status updates, it may be a good idea to create custom SwingWorker derivatives in this manner and post *those* on the ExecutorService. (You should for the time being not attempt to run multiple SwingWorkers concurrently as the current SwingWorker implementation effectively does not permit it.)